# Swift @objc protocol with optional variable CGFloat?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I declare an optional variable of type CGFloat in a `@objc protocol`?

I have

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var myvar: CGFloat? { get set }
}
```

I get the error "Property cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var myvar: NSNumber? { get set }
}
```

Then you can make a conversion from `NSNumber` to `CGFloat`